# Calculate CPU% by process from /proc/stat and /proc/<pid>/stat

Tags: python, linux

We don't have the possibility to install modules like `psutil` on some boxes, thus I decided to write a simple script to calculate the CPU percentage by the given PID.

It uses `/proc/stat` to get **CPU** times and `/proc/<pid>/stat` to get the process CPU usage.

I added `top` output here, just to compare results and to be sure it's (about) correct. But - I don't like to use external utilities in Python scripts, thus `top` will be removed.

- OS: CentOS 6.5
- Python: 2.6.6

Next - it calculates % of CPU, taken by this process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import time
import subprocess

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    pid = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print('No PID specified. Usage: %s <PID>' % os.path.basename(__file__))
    sys.exit(1)


def proct(pid):
    try:
        with open(os.path.join('/proc/', pid, 'stat'), 'r') as pidfile:
            proctimes = pidfile.readline()
            # get utime from /proc/<pid>/stat, 14 item
            utime = proctimes.split(' ')[13]
            # get stime from proc/<pid>/stat, 15 item
            stime = proctimes.split(' ')[14]
            # count total process used time
            proctotal = int(utime) + int(stime)
            return(float(proctotal))
    except IOError as e:
        print('ERROR: %s' % e)
        sys.exit(2)


def cput():
    try:
        with open('/proc/stat', 'r') as procfile:
            cputimes = procfile.readline()
            cputotal = 0
            # count from /proc/stat: user, nice, system, idle, iowait, irc, softirq, steal, guest
            for i in cputimes.split(' ')[2:]:
                i = int(i)
                cputotal = (cputotal + i)
            return(float(cputotal))
    except IOError as e:
        print('ERROR: %s' % e)
        sys.exit(3)

# assign start values before loop them
proctotal = proct(pid)
cputotal = cput()

try:
    while True:

        # for test, to compare results
        proc = subprocess.Popen("top -p %s -b -n 1 | grep -w mysql | awk '{print $9}'" % pid, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        cpu_percentage = proc.communicate()
        print('With TOP: %s' % (cpu_percentage[0].rstrip('\n')))

        pr_proctotal = proctotal
        pr_cputotal = cputotal

        proctotal = proct(pid)
        cputotal = cput()

        try:
            res = ((proctotal - pr_proctotal) / (cputotal - pr_cputotal) * 100)
            print('With script: %s\n' % round(res, 1))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pass

        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(0)
```

And its results:

> ```
> $ ./cpu_usage_by_proccess.py 24846
> With TOP: 0.0
> With script: 0.0
>
> With TOP: 0.0
> With script: 0.0
>
> With TOP: 0.0
> With script: 0.7
>
> With TOP: 14.0
> With script: 4.8
>
> With TOP: 32.0
> With script: 34.4
>
> With TOP: 29.9
> With script: 32.6
>
> With TOP: 30.0
> With script: 35.1
>
> With TOP: 18.0
> With script: 26.5
>
> With TOP: 20.0
> With script: 20.6
> ```

What's done incorrectly here, or what can be done better (maybe a more "Pythonic way")?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have code outside of functions or an `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard (which isn't ideal in itself), both *above and below* the various function definitions, which makes the code relatively difficult to follow. I would structure the script as follows:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import time

def proct(pid):
    ...

def cput():
    ...

def main(pid):
    ...

def parse_args():
    ...
    return pid

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(parse_args())
```

Now if you want to `import` this functionality elsewhere, it's easy. Also, note that I have made the imports alphabetical, per [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

---

I would factor out any temporary variables, e.g.

```
proctotal = int(utime) + int(stime)
return(float(proctotal))
```

can be written:

```
return float(int(utime) + int(stime))
```

---

Try not to do the same thing twice, e.g.

```
proctimes = pidfile.readline()
utime = proctimes.split(' ')[13]
stime = proctimes.split(' ')[14]
```

could be rewritten

```
proctimes = pidfile.readline().split(' ')
utime = proctime[13] # you could also call int here
stime = proctime[14]
```

which only calls `str.split` once.

---

Consider adding [docstrings](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to your functions, rather than the inline comments (some of which are redundant - `utime = proctimes.split(' ')[13]` does not need the explanation `# get utime from /proc/<pid>/stat, 14 item`, which just adds an extra line to read). Better function names would also help with clarity - e.g. `cpu_total` rather than `cput`.

---

The main part of `cput`:

```
cputimes = procfile.readline()
cputotal = 0
for i in cputimes.split(' ')[2:]:
    i = int(i)
    cputotal = (cputotal + i)
return(float(cputotal))
```

can be rewritten in a functional style:

```
return sum(map(float, procfile.readline().split(' ')[2:]))
```

or using a generator expression:

```
return sum(float(s) for s in procfile.readline().split(' ')[2:])
```

Comment: Idon't familiar with `sum` and `map` yet, thus - this part will left as it is, for now... All other - thanks. Moving everything to functions looks much better (usually I do so with '''Docstrings''' there, just... little bit lazy today :-)).

Comment: I wouldn't factor out `proctotal`. Explicitly mentioning that it's the total makes it, well explicit and I don't have to think about what adding `utime` and `stime` means. Note that this is only important because `utime` and `stime` are abbreviations, and it's not immediately clear what they're for.

Answer (score 7):

I can't comment on the correctness but here's an improved version of your `cput` function. I'll start with the final version and then work towards it from the original code. **Note the bug fix: [2:] should be [1:].**

```
def read_cpu_usage(stat_path='/proc/stat'):
    with open(stat_path) as stat_file:
        return sum(float(time) for time in next(stat_file).split()[1:])
```

---

Remove the try/catch exit. Let Python crash loudly so we get the whole trackback

```
def cput():
    with open('/proc/stat', 'r') as procfile:
        cputimes = procfile.readline()
        cputotal = 0
        # count from /proc/stat: user, nice, system, idle, iowait, irc, softirq, steal, guest
        for i in cputimes.split(' ')[1:]:
            i = int(i)
            cputotal = (cputotal + i)
        return(float(cputotal))
```

---

Use the built-in `sum` to perform the summation.

```
def cput():
    with open('/proc/stat', 'r') as procfile:
        cputimes = procfile.readline()
        cputotal = sum(int(i) for i in cputimes.split(' ')[1:])
        return(float(cputotal))
```

---

Parse directly to float so we don't need to do two different conversions.

```
def cput():
    with open('/proc/stat', 'r') as procfile:
        cputimes = procfile.readline()
        cputotal = sum(float(i) for i in cputimes.split(' ')[1:])
        return(cputotal)
```

---

Return the total directly [removing the temporary variable](http://refactoring.com/catalog/inlineTemp.html).

```
def cput():
    with open('/proc/stat', 'r') as procfile:
        cputimes = procfile.readline()
        return sum(float(i) for i in cputimes.split(' ')[1:])
```

---

Split at white-space, rather an a single space.

```
def cput():
    with open('/proc/stat', 'r') as procfile:
        cputimes = procfile.readline()
        return sum(float(i) for i in cputimes.split()[1:])
```

---

Default mode is read and normally implicit.

```
def cput():
    with open('/proc/stat') as procfile:
        cputimes = procfile.readline()
        return sum(float(i) for i in cputimes.split()[1:])
```

---

Take advantage that `File` are generators and remove temporary variable.

```
def cput():
    with open('/proc/stat') as procfile:
        return sum(float(i) for i in next(procfile).split()[1:])
```

---

(Possibly) better names.

```
def read_cpu_usage():
    with open('/proc/stat') as stat_file:
        return sum(float(time) for time in next(stat_file).split()[1:])
```

---

Make the path a parameter so that it can be swapped out testing with a mock file.

```
def read_cpu_usage(stat_path='/proc/stat'):
    with open(stat_path) as stat_file:
        return sum(float(time) for time in next(stat_file).split()[1:])
```

---

**Bonus: Avoid the list copy**

I'd use this version my code base but only because I know my team (i.e., one other person I've working with since we started university together in 2008) is comfortable with iterators and generators. The performance/memory gain is negligible but, for me, it the principle and consistency. *Note*: I've forgone PEP8's double line separating for space, but include in your code base.

```
from itertools import islice

def read_cpu_usage(stat_path='/proc/stat'):
    with open(stat_path) as stat_file:
        return sum(float(time) for time in
                islice(next(stat_file).split(), 1, None))
```

---

**Bonus: Close the file fast**

If the code is run in a much larger, concurrent program. Closing files fast helps keep away from your file descriptor limit.

```
from itertools import islice

def read_cpu_usage(stat_path='/proc/stat'):
    with open(stat_path) as stat_file:
        cpu_stat_line = next(stat_file)
    return sum(float(time) for time in 
            islice(cpu_stat_line.split(), 1, None))
```

---

**Bonus: Split the read and parse**

This makes it easier to test and, more importantly, reuse.

```
from itertools import islice

def read_cpu_usage(stat_path='/proc/stat'):
    with open(stat_path) as stat_file:
        return next(stat_file)

def parse_cpu_usage(cpu_stat_line):
    return sum(float(time) for time in
            islice(cpu_stat_line.split(), 1, None))
```

---

**Bonus: Provide a convenience function**

```
from itertools import islice

def get_cpu_usage(*args, **kwargs):
    return parse_cpu_usage(read_cpu_usage(*args, **kwargs))

def read_cpu_usage(stat_path='/proc/stat'):
    with open(stat_path) as stat_file:
        return next(stat_file)

def parse_cpu_usage(cpu_stat_line):
    return sum(float(time) for time in
            islice(cpu_stat_line.split(), 1, None))
```

---

**Bouns: Group the functionality into class**

```
from itertools import islice

class CPUUsage(object):
    def __init__(self, stat_path='/proc/stat'):
        self.stat_path = stat_path

    def get(self):
        return self.parse(self.read(self.stat_path))
    __call__ = get

    @staticmethod
    def read(stat_path):
        with open(stat_path) as stat_file:
            return next(stat_file)

    @staticmethod
    def parse(cpu_stat_line):
        return sum(float(time) for time in
                islice(cpu_stat_line.split(), 1, None))
```

---

**Bonus: Support the File API**

Allow read from anything that implements the File API.

```
from itertools import islice

class CPUUsage(object):
    def __init__(self, stat_path='/proc/stat'):
        self.stat_path = stat_path

    def get(self):
        return self.parse(self.read(self.stat_path))
    __call__ = get

    @staticmethod
    def read(stat_source):
        if isinstance(stat_source, basestring):
            open_stat = lambda: open(stat_source)
        else:
            open_stat = lambda: stat_source
        with open_stat() as stat_file:
            return next(stat_file)

    @staticmethod
    def parse(cpu_stat_line):
        return sum(float(time) for time in
                islice(cpu_stat_line.split(), 1, None))
```

---

**Bonus: Put it in it's own module...**

Put it on the Python path, never write the code again. Also provide a convenience module-level function for the 99% use case.

```
from itertools import islice

__all__ = ['CPUUsage', 'get_cpu_usage']

_instance = None

def _get_instance():
    global _instance
    if _instance is None:
        _instance = CPUUsage()
    return _instance

def get_cpu_usage():
    return _get_instance().get()

class CPUUsage(object):
    def __init__(self, stat_path='/proc/stat'):
        self.stat_path = stat_path

    def get(self):
        return self.parse(self.read(self.stat_path))
    __call__ = get

    @staticmethod
    def read(stat_source):
        if isinstance(stat_source, basestring):
            open_stat = lambda: open(stat_source)
        else:
            open_stat = lambda: stat_source
        with open_stat() as stat_file:
            return next(stat_file)

    @staticmethod
    def parse(cpu_stat_line):
        return sum(float(time) for time in
                islice(cpu_stat_line.split(), 1, None))
```

Answer (score 4):

@jonrsharpe has listed a number of presentation, structural, and functional changes, but I'm just going to run through some of the bugs... ;-)

---

### TOP takes a second

Your basic program structure is:

```
proctotal = proct(pid)
cputotal = cput()

try:
    while True:

        # for test, to compare results
        proc = subprocess.Popen("top -p %s -b -n 1 | grep -w mysql | awk '{print $9}'" % pid, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        cpu_percentage = proc.communicate()
        print('With TOP: %s' % (cpu_percentage[0].rstrip('\n')))

        pr_proctotal = proctotal
        pr_cputotal = cputotal

        proctotal = proct(pid)
        cputotal = cput()

        try:
            res = ((proctotal - pr_proctotal) / (cputotal - pr_cputotal) * 100)
            print('With script: %s\n' % round(res, 1))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pass

        time.sleep(1)
```

So, what does that do? It takes a reading from the stat files, then it runs top, which taks a second, then it re-reads the stat files, and prints the results for that second to match against TOP. Finally it waits a second, then loops.

On the next loop, it has already waited a second, then another second for the top, so the subsequent loops report the top times for only the second second of a 2-second wait time. Your comparison numbers will never match accurately.

Additionally, when you remove the top comparison, your loop will be:

```
proctotal = proct(pid)
cputotal = cput()

try:
    while True:

        pr_proctotal = proctotal
        pr_cputotal = cputotal

        proctotal = proct(pid)
        cputotal = cput()

        try:
            res = ((proctotal - pr_proctotal) / (cputotal - pr_cputotal) * 100)
            print('With script: %s\n' % round(res, 1))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pass

        time.sleep(1)
```

and the first time through the loop it will always display 0 because it never waited between readings. You should put the `sleep(1)` as the first thing inside the loop, or, while you are using top as a test, you should comment out the `sleep(1)` because the top call essentially *is* a `sleep(1)`.

### /proc/stat

Your processing of the stat files is broken.

The format for the file is (taken from my machine):

```
abox:~> cat /proc/stat
cpu  19407338 17453351 34946083 2361383858 59819619 2748 2690630 0 0 0
cpu0 8423923 911989 15385729 250602858 21892989 2614 2574046 0 0 0
cpu1 1057945 1098915 1028942 309149453 2009689 2 7469 0 0 0
cpu2 3439928 4831311 5750843 283795300 13861225 74 42971 0 0 0
.....
```

You read the first line and process that. That's the right thing to do, but, what you do is:

```
        cputotal = 0
        # count from /proc/stat: user, nice, system, idle, iowait, irc, softirq, steal, guest
        for i in cputimes.split(' ')[2:]:
            i = int(i)
            cputotal = (cputotal + i)
        return(float(cputotal))
```

The best documentation for that file [is here(http://www.mjmwired.net)](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt#1212):

- user: normal processes executing in user mode
- nice: niced processes executing in user mode
- system: processes executing in kernel mode
- idle: twiddling thumbs
- iowait: waiting for I/O to complete
- irq: servicing interrupts
- softirq: servicing softirqs
- steal: involuntary wait
- guest: running a normal guest
- guest_nice: running a niced guest

Now, the first line is

> ```
>      cpu  19407338 17453351 34946083 2361383858 59819619 2748 2690630 0 0 0
> ```

You use the array slice `[2:]`, which had me confused for a long time. TO me this was just counting the `nice` times and on, and not counting the `user` time at all. I never saw tha tyou were splitting on `' '` instead of just whitespace, so. Making your code depend on the amount of whitespace is a problem, and will become a bug at some future time, and, it appears, is a problem right now. You should split on whitespace, and count fields, instead of counting spaces....

Now, the last two columns are 'guest' time, and these values are double-counted in the user times. Your current code double-counts that time, and will lead to errors in your computations.

Your array slice should be splitting on whitespace, and should only be summing: `[1:9]`

### /proc/{pid}/stat

Your calculation here is right, but I would do the split just once, and read the two fields in one slice.

Comment: > Your totals are off // well... if take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367857/accurate-calculation-of-cpu-usage-given-in-percentage-in-linux "According the htop source code" - need to calculate total spent CPU time, including idle, irc etc. And it sounds logical.

Comment: @setevoy - My solution to your bug is wrong, but you still have a bug... a significant one. You are not counting the user time at all, just the nice time.

Comment: Note, you should be slicing stat line `[1:]` at least, not `[2:]`.

Comment: Arghhh, you split on `' '` and not `\s`... horrible, horrible. comment it at least.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how relevant this is, but I saw one small issue in the original script (possibly elsewhere):

In the comparison with top, grep is used to filter out results, but "hardcoded" to mysql, which doesn't seem to be generic... i.e.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("top -p %s -b -n 1 | grep -w **mysql** | awk '{print $9}'" % pid, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I'd suggest replacing "mysql" with the process name that is linked to the PID in question.

Answer (score 2):

All the solutions which are parsing `/proc/$PID/stat` manually are broken!

A process may contain a space character, and then changes the index of splitting it by whitespace:

```py
import setproctitle, os, glob

setproctitle.setproctitle('foo bar baz')
[
    open(fn).read().split()[3]
    for fn in glob.glob('/proc/*/stat')
    if not os.path.isdir(fn)
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! When you mention "_All the solutions which are parsing /proc/$PID/stat manually are broken!_" does that refer to the OPs code, like "_It uses `/proc/stat` to get **CPU** times and `/proc/<pid>/stat` to get the process CPU usage_", or other answers?

Comment: The OP's code is also splitting by ` ` space, so is also vulnerable.